# Make Sprite Invisible From Upward To Downward

Tags: android, andengine

I am working on andengine GLES 2.I want to make sprite invisible from upward to downward.Actualy I am working on a game. In which user will press the drinking button to drink the juice. I have to show the effect that as long as user press the button juice is going down in the glass or cup.I have a sprite of juice behind the sprite of glass. I want to make this sprite to show the effect of drinking juice. As in real life when we take a sip juice goes down in the glass. Kindly help me on this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using a ScaleModifier or ScaleAtModifier, which is an animation modifier that scales the image by a certain amount (in your case, shrinks), over a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

You have three choices in this task.

1. User ScaleYModifier to scale down your sprite.
2. Change height your sprite as per your requirement.
3. Prepare sprite sheet from the designer for this task. On sip change tile index. This thing create nice effect as far as your designer create it.